# How can I retrieve the value from a column instead of the link using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm using a projection to retrieve a list of matches with the teams inline.

Projection:

```
@Projection(name = "matchInlineTeams", types = { Match.class })
    public interface MatchInlineTeams {

    Team getHomeTeam();
    Long getHomeTeamGoals();
    Long getAwayTeamGoals();
    Team getAwayTeam();
}
```

And my result is a collection of these:

```
{
  "homeTeam" : {
    "teamName" : "Banfield",
    "teamFoundation" : "1896-01-21T03:00:00.000+0000",
    "teamCity" : 73,
    "teamCountry" : "ARG",
    "handler" : { },
    "hibernateLazyInitializer" : { }
  },
  "homeTeamGoals" : 2,
  "awayTeamGoals" : 0,
  "awayTeam" : {
    "teamName" : "Gimnasia (LP)",
    "teamFoundation" : "1887-06-03T03:00:00.000+0000",
    "teamCity" : 76,
    "teamCountry" : "ARG",
    "handler" : { },
    "hibernateLazyInitializer" : { }
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "goals" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/goals"
    },
    "homeTeam" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/homeTeam"
    },
    "competition" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/competition"
    },
    "matchStadium" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/matchStadium"
    },
    "awayTeam" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/awayTeam"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to do many calculations for a stats app and I have the logic in the front end so to build a match history between two teams, I need to make this request and it is taking about a second to retrieve everything, which is fine.

My problem now is that I want to build a table out of history matches, therefore I can't request the matches between 2 teams, I have to request all matches where a team participated.

Anyway, now I can't use that because instead of 200 matches, I get 3500 as a response, so it takes around 20 seconds to build the response.

I'm guessing that is because the API is returning all links and resolving both teams for each object which is fine but I don't need it so. Is there a way for me to create a projection (or any other class) that will return the literal version of my column instead of resolving the object reference?

I want my result to be like this:

```
{
  "homeTeam" : 10,
  "homeTeamGoals" : 2,
  "awayTeamGoals" : 0,
  "awayTeam" : 36,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
  }
}
```

When my table is built, I will call the teams endpoint to resolve the team's names.

So considering this, what I really need is to make it faster (like 20 times faster). So if this is not the right path, I would very much appreciate a suggestion.